# How to hide recipient name in sent mail in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

When I send emails to recipients they receive mail with custom names from my Gmail. How can I disable this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you will have to remove the custom name in the to field manually.

GMail puts it there automatically.

Comment: yes.. just keep the email and you're set